Tools for examining usermode memory
What tools are available for examining detailed memory allocations in user mode processes?  For example:

What are the flags at the virtual page level?
What are the physical addresses (and their flags) mapped to virtual pages?
List the pages that are swapped out (when the system is under memory pressure)?
Which pages are in a copy-on-write state vs. unallocated vs. allocated to a process?
How do you test changes to the Linux Kernel memory manager?

In my experience, memory management (on live systems) is messy and nondeterministic.  I’m curious if anyone knows about tools for testing/examining memory at a page level?
I feel like I’m missing something and there must be tools that help people with these sorts of questions.
I know the Kernel gives us a few windows into what it's doing:

/proc/self/maps
/proc/self/pagemap
/proc/iomem
/proc/kpagecount
/proc/kpageflags

... but I haven't found a tool that makes it easy to visualize this information.
Any feedback you can offer would be much appreciated and I sincerely appreciate your time.
Very Respectfully,
Mark Nelson

I think we have an operating system so we don't have to care about these things.  These items are critical for the kernel, but generally irrelevant for the user.  Visualizing these would be difficult and messy, and probably only of interest to a kernel developer.  Top and similar tools should give stats on these, but not per page info.
